# How deal with NVM in production environments?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, iptables, ports

I am using NVM to develop a Sails web application. I have installed node v0.12.7, through NVM and I use this version to run the website.

```
nvm use 0.12.7
sails lift
```

Sails uses port 1337 by default, but for production environment we change it to 443. The problem is that this port requires root privileges, and NVM is installed for just one user. So if I try sudo sails lift, I get an error saying that **sails is not installed**.

What is the most effective way for dealing with that issue? How can I use NVM to develop my project and deploy it?

I have thought different possible solutions but I don't know if they are good or insecure.

1. Forwarding ports using `iptables`. The problem with that is socket could not works beacuse a proxy.
2. Change permissions for a port. Could be security risk if node have vulnerabilities.
3. Install NVM with root. The problem is that I uses NVM to avoid use `sudo` for deploy or run applications, and this will force me to do it.

What are the best practices in this context?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would solution 1 not work? Port forwarding is not proxying. Anyway, my preferred solution is to always have a battle-tested front-end server like nginx or apache2 and then use them to reverse proxy the web app. There are other advantages as well but the primary reason for me would be security -- it adds one more layer to hack.

Comment: Agree - Reverse proxy via nginx works perfectly for this scenario including the sockets. I wouldn't consider using option 2 and 3 at all. Option 1 or our new option 4 = nginx/apache/lighttpd etc.

Happy to share my nginx config if you run in to any issues and decide to go down that route.

Comment: If you are referring to websockets (like socket.io) then reverse proxying is a bit tricky but is doable (I've done it before). Just google for websocket proxy for the server of your choice. Though you may need to use a more recent version of the server on your production server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For security reasons it is not recommended to have NodeJS running with root privileges.

You can try running your application on a port accessible for a different user without root privileges and then configure a reverse proxy from on the 443 port. This is what I did using nginx as the reverse proxy which can be configured easily to perform this task as well as handling the SSL traffic.

On this link you can find more information about configuring nginx as reverse proxy, it is from the official documentation:
https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue doing the following.

I have change the owner and the group of node.

```
which node # gives a string with the path to node
sudo chown root:root path_to_node
sudo chmod u+s path_to_node
```

That way, whatever user executing node will do it with the owner privileges. And in this case, the owner is root and its privileges are enough to use ports under 1024.

What do you think about this solution?

Comment: Probably not the best approach. You can avoid all of these permissions issues by making sure your deploy user is not root, install everything under that user, all deploy commmands should be run by that non-root user, and then you have your server (nginx, Apache, whatever) listen on 443 and have it proxy requests to whatever internal port your app runs on. Seriously, don’t do what you’re doing. It’s bad practice and insecure.